# Creating a bi-directional @ManyToAny relationship in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a M-N join table named `AssociatedDocuments` that looks somewhat like this:

```
|------------|----------|------------|
| RecordType | RecordId | DocumentId |
|------------|----------|------------|
|   ITEM     |     1    |      5     |
|   ITEM     |     2    |      2     |
| WORKORDER  |     5    |      2     |
|------------|----------|------------|
```

On one end of the `@ManyToAny` relationship, I have a collection of polymorphic entities, two of which are `Item` and `WorkOrder`. Each of these can have a `Document` associated with it.

On the `Document` side, I have the following method in my entity:

```
@ManyToAny(metaColumn = @Column(name = "RecordType"))
@AnyMetaDef(
        idType = "integer", metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
                @MetaValue(targetEntity = Item.class, value = "ITEM"),
                @MetaValue(targetEntity = WorkOrder.class, value = "WORKORDER")
        })
@JoinTable(name = "AssociatedDocuments",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "DocumentId")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "RecordId")})
public Set<HasDocumensAndUrls> getAssociatedEntities() {
    return associatedEntities;
}
```

For example, if I am currently working with `Document` with ID **2**, I'll get a collection with two items: One with an `Item` instance and the other with a `WorkOrder` instance. When I add items to this collection and persist it through Hibernate, a new entry in the `AssociatedDocuments` table will be added automatically for me.

What I need is a way for this to work from the opposite end of the relationship as well. Presently I have a `@ManyToMany` relationship defined on both `Item` and `WorkOrder` that uses a `@WhereJoinTable` to filter the results as follows:

```
@Override
@ManyToMany
@Cascade({PERSIST, MERGE, SAVE_UPDATE})
@JoinTable(name = "AssociatedDocuments",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "RecordId")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "DocumentId")})
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "RecordType = 'WORKORDER'")
public Set<Document> getDocuments() {
    return this.documents;
}
```

This works fine for retrieving existing records, but I can't add a new `Document` instance to the collection to have it create the relationship due to the `RecordType` column. I'm aware of `@SQLInsert`, but this feels like a hack-y means of achieving the solution, given that I have to effectively guess at the order of the parameters for the `@SQLInsert` clause.

Is there a proper way to solve this that I'm unaware of, or will I need to resort to using the `@SQLInsert` annotation on my `@ManyToMany` relationships?

For reference purposes, my `WorkOrder` entity is defined as such (Item is similar):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WorkOrders")
public class WorkOrder implements HasDocumensAndUrls { ... }
```

and `Document` is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Documents")
public class Document { ... }
```

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhatami That does not have anything to do with `@ManyToAny`

Comment: The [javadoc][1] says:

> Defines a ToMany association pointing to different entity types.
> Matching the according entity type is done through a metadata
> discriminator column. This kind of mapping should be only marginal.

So instead of having a ManyToMany between Student and Course, you could have a ManyToAny between Student and [Course or Teacher], and the metadata discriminator column would say, for a given row, if it points to a Course or to a Teacher.


  [1]: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ManyToAny.html